# iOS Local Notification Error

Tags: ios, timer, notifications, alert

I have this code:

> ```
> UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
> [notification setAlertBody:@"This is a message"];
> [notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10]];
> [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
> [application setSchedualLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]];
> ```

This works fine in the `AppDelegate.m` or `(-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:­(UIApplication *)application)` but it does not work in the `ViewController`. I wanted this exact thing to happen when the user clicks a button so I need this code in `ViewController` not `AppDelegate`. How can I change this code so it can do the same thing in the `ViewController`! Thanks so much!

Comment: this code will work in viewControllers also ,some where else you went wrong i think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following link shows that we can only create and schedule Local Notification in a AppDelegate file:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

in the following methods:
UIApplication 
scheduleLocalNotification:
 or presentLocalNotificationNow:

But the catch here is you can always get the instance of the AppDelegate and call these methods:
MyApplicationDelegate *appDelegate = (MyApplicationDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

then call - [appDelegate presentLocalNotificationNow:LOcalnotificaton]

Comment: You do not need a delegate, you need UIApplication instance itself, your code won't work.

Comment: oops made this mistake, please ignore intent was to make use of UIApplication :     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];

Answer (score 1):

Um, get the current application object

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setSchedualLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]];
```